How to simulate response data that varies over time in R
I'm simulating some data for a power analysis using R, where we will test children's response times in an experimental setting and see if this predicts later language skills. The children will be grouped according to a third variable (here Group). The statistical model we'll be using looks something like this: language ~ RT * Timepoint + Group. I'm trying to figure out how to simulate a variable, RT, that changes in an expected direction according to another variable, Timepoint.
I'm having some difficulty creating the RT variable so that it varies over time in a way that is correlated within subject. It should increase over time with an effect of around 0.2, but of course this will vary across participants whereby some have larger increases and some smaller (with a jittered effect of around 0.1). Similarly, some participants will have longer looking times overall, and some shorter.
The code we have so far is something like this:
# First specify the values for each variable in the model

SimulatedData <- function(
 MeanIntrcpt = 37.5, # baseline language score
 MeanSlope = 14.63, # overall effect of group on language score
 Group = 0.39, # estimated effect of group on language score
 time_slope = .2, # estimated effect of Timepoint on reaction time
 n_subjects = 60, # number of subjects
 n_timepoints = 3, # number of timepoints
 RandIntrcpt_subjects = 0.2, # Random intercept for subjects
 RandSlope_subjects = 0.2,   # Random slope for subjects
 Randslope_subject_time = 0.1 # Jittered effect of time between subjects
           ){

# Simulate data to reflect our subjects

SimulatedSubjects <- faux::rnorm_multi(
 n = n_subjects, 
 mu = 0, 
 sd = c(RandIntrcpt_subjects, RandSlope_subjects, Randslope_subject_time), 
 varnames = c("RandIntrcpt_subjects_StdDev", "RandSlope_subjects_StdDev", 
                     "RandSlope_subjects_time_StdDev")) %>%
 mutate(ChildID = faux::make_id(nrow(.), "S_"),
               Group = sample(c(1, 2), 60, replace= T))        # assign half the participants to group 1/group 2

# Simulate data to reflect timepoints

timepoints <- data.frame(Timepoint = seq_len(n_timepoints))

# create the combined data frame - simulated subjects crossed with timepoints

SimulatedSubjectsAndStimuli <- crossing(SimulatedSubjects, timepoints)

# Simulate RT data, 60 subjects * 3 timepoints = 180 rows

SimulatedSubjectsAndStimuli <- SimulatedSubjectsAndStimuli %>%
  mutate(RT = runif(n_subjects*n_timepoints, min = -0.5, max = 0.5))

}

SimulatedData <- SimulatedData()

SimulatedData <- SimulatedData()

> head(SimulatedData)
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  RandIntrcpt_subjects_StdDev RandSlope_subjects_StdDev RandSlope_subjects_time_StdDev ChildID Group Timepoint      RT
                        <dbl>                     <dbl>                          <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>     <int>   <dbl>
1                      -0.584                    0.0153                         -0.137 S_42        1         1 -0.452 
2                      -0.584                    0.0153                         -0.137 S_42        1         2 -0.265 
3                      -0.584                    0.0153                         -0.137 S_42        1         3 -0.0435
4                      -0.412                   -0.157                           0.169 S_15        1         1 -0.491 
5                      -0.412                   -0.157                           0.169 S_15        1         2 -0.176 
6                      -0.412                   -0.157                           0.169 S_15        1         3  0.152 
> 

This output essentially looks how we want it to look, except that the RT variable does not vary predictably for each child across the three timepoints. How can we vary this by an increase of about 0.2, with a between-participant standard deviation of around 0.1, within the simulated data?

Sounds like you first need to figure out the statistical principles and how to specify them. If you strike out in front of this coding audience you should try   http://CrossValidated.com

@IRTFM thank you - I tried at cross-validated and the post was closed due to being a programming query!

CV.com requires that you pose the question as a request for the principles and procedures but NOT as a request for a specific set of code in a particular language. You should have asked just how to deal with this issue: “ I'm having some difficulty creating the RT variable so that it varies over time in a way that is correlated within subject.”
